# How to bind gridview inside a repeater?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, repeater

I want to bind gridview which is inside a repeater. My code is

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rep_UnAssignComps" runat="server">

         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="rep_DataSimilarToBacthid" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
                width: 375px;" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Test" DataField="Test" />
                </Columns>

            </asp:GridView>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you have to fire repeater's ItemDataBound event. In which you have to find gridview then bind it as following:-

```
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then


        Dim grd As GridView = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rep_DataSimilarToBacthid"), GridView)
        grd.DataSource = dt

        grd.DataBind()
   end if
```

Answer (score 6):

If your entity whitch is bounded to the repeate have necessare data source (list of entities for example) just specify to the `DataSource` of the `GridView` with this property.

```
<asp:GridView ID="rep_DataSimilarToBacthid" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
            width: 375px;" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%# Eval("GridDataSource") %>'>
```

where `GridDataSource` is collection of items.

Also you can define the method witch will specify the datasource at the codebehind and call it:

**Page.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="rep_DataSimilarToBacthid" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
            width: 375px;" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSource='<%# GetGridViewData(Container.DataItem) %>'>
```

**CodeBehind.cs**

```
public List<GridViewDataItem> GetGridViewData(Object repeaterObject)
{
    // define what you need here
}
```

Also, check the posts:

[Binding gridview inside a repeater](http://forums.asp.net/t/1087353.aspx)

[Adding Gridview nested in Repeater in ASP.NET 2.0](http://techbrij.com/217/adding-gridview-nested-in-repeater-in-asp-net-2-0)

[Repeater within Gridview in C# ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/repeater_in_gridview.aspx) - the concept the same in your case

[Bind Repeater's DataRow to GridView's DataSource](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/bind-repeaters-datarow-gridviews-datasource-t2884858.html)